# How to find the area of a cardioid using multivariable calculus?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator

So I have the following three questions (and no solutions to them sadly). I wanted to know if my results for a) and b) are correct and how I should proceed for c).

---

Given is  the following ellipsoid : $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2} \leq 1$$ and the following questions :

a) Calculate the volume of the ellipsoid 
b) Calculate the flux of $V=(x-3xy^2,y^3-2xyz,xz^2+2z)$ through the surface of the ellispoid toward the exterior
c) Given is the cardiode $(x^2+y^2-2x)^2=4(x^2+y^2)$. Determine the "area which is enclosed by the cardioid" (german: Flächeninhalt).

---

a) As usual, we make the substitutions $\hat{x}=\frac{x}{a}$, $\hat{y}=\frac{y}{b}$ and $\hat{z}=\frac{z}{c}$, we get $dx=ad\hat{x}, dy=bd\hat{y}, dz = cd\hat{z}$, so now we have a sphere and can set up our triple integral in spherical coordinates $$abc \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}1*r^2sin(\phi)d\phi d\theta dr$$ which after integration yields the well known $abc \frac{4\pi}{3}$

b) The divergence of $V$ is simply 3. Thus we can use the divergence theorem : we have a triple integral (i.e. the volume of your ellipsoid) over the divergence of our vector field. In our case, the divergence doesn't depend on x, y or z, so we simply get our volume times our divergence, i.e. $abc \frac{4\pi}{3}*3=abc 4 \pi$

 
c) Now, here I really have some troubles, because I'm supposed to calculate the "area enclosed" using multivariable calculus, i.e. not just applying a well known formula. How am I supposed to proceed ? Should I use polar coordinates or what ?

Thanks for your help !

---

Edit 11/01/2019: 
 
In fact, c) can be solved really easily. If we just use polar coordinates $x=r\cos(\theta), y=r\sin(\theta)$, we get $(r^2-2r\cos(\theta))^2=4r^2$. If we take the square root, the right side has to be positive because $r$ cannot be negative, so we get $2r$. For the left side, we have $\pm(r^2-2r\cos(\theta))=2r$ . So either $r(r-2\cos(\theta)-2)=0$ and either $r=0$ or $r=2(\cos(\theta)+1)$ or $r(-r+2\cos(\theta)-2)=0$ and $r=0$ or $r=2(\cos(\theta)-1)$ which is not possible because $r$ would be negative if not zero.

Thus $r=2(\cos(\theta)+1)$. Now we can set up our double integral:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2(\cos(\theta)+1)}1 r dr d\theta=\int_{0}^{2\pi}2(\cos(\theta)+1)^2 d\theta =2 \int_{0}^{2\pi}(\cos^2(\theta)+2\cos(\theta)+1) d\theta=2(\pi+ 0 +2\pi)=6\pi$$

Comment: (c) yes, use polar coordinates. Let's see what you get

Comment: @Lozenges Ok, I will try

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: (c) is largely unrelated to (a) and (b). You should ask one question per ... question.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok, I will think about it next time. Thank you.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen By the way, may I just ask you if you agree with my results for a) and b) ? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Write the equation in polar coordinates, and try to draw what it is.
- Construct a simple vector field whose divergence is identically 1, and then use the divergence theorem (or Green's theorem) to reduce the area into an integral over the curve.

Comment: Well, we haven't covered Green's theorem yet, so I don't think I am allowed to use it.

Comment: @Poujh Then it is polar

Comment: I did it wrong. I should get $2\int_{0}^{2\pi}1-2\cos(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)$ which evaluates to $6\pi$, which seems to be correct given that I also obtain $6\pi$ using the area formula $\frac{3}{2}\pi a^2$ where $a=-2$

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "polar" ? And just to be clear, is what I just said above all I need to do ? I mean, just use $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}r^2$ where $r=-2(1-cos(\theta))$ ?

Comment: You have a formula for computing area in polar coordinates. Use that formula.

Comment: You need to be sure how the shape looks. Don't blindly apply the formula.

Comment: yeah, I drew it and it seems to be $2\pi$ periodic.

Comment: But I just have one question : the question c) about calculating the area of the cardioid is worth 4 times more points than question a) or b). I don't understand why, given that we just need to find the radius and then use our integral formula, while in a) and b), the calculations seem to be more "complicated" to say the very least. Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: @Poujh: I thought c) was an application of the divergence theorem, but you said you did not study it. However, I am puzzled because you used it in b).

Comment: we have covered the divergence theorem but not green's theorem

Comment: @Poujh: So you can use the 2D divergence theorem in c)